# Find and replace a word in all files based on file pattern

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression

I have a variable called  `"User": "x-73098"` in multiple files and the file names like `astro_root_sys-dev.txt.`

How to find all the files which have "User": "x-73098" variable and replace that variable value dynamically from `"User": "x-73098"` to `"User": "sys_user"`.

User value (x-73098) is not going to be the same in all files, the numbers after x- varies in many files.

Comment: Is that all there is on the line? Multiple per file or just one?Always that exact pattern?

Comment: Not multiple per file, but its just one per file. and we can use the file pattern as astro_*_sys-*.txt

Answer (score 0):

This `sed` linear will search the documents that contain "unknown" and repalce it with "sys_user":

```
sed -i 's/"unknown"/"sys_user"/g' *.txt
```

In order to change all strings ends with `-73098`:

If x is a number:

```
sed 's/[0-9]-73098/"sys_user"/g'  *.txt
```

If x is small letter:

```
sed 's/[a-z]-73098/"sys_user"/g'  *.txt
```

If x is capital letter:

```
sed 's/[A-Z]-73098/"sys_user"/g'  *.txt
```

If x is capital or small letter or a number:

```
sed -i 's/[a-zA-Z0-9]-73098/User: "sys_user"/g' *.txt
```

Comment: I have updated the question, actually, the user value "x-73098" varies from file to file.

Comment: Here is the script I ran, and output also mentioned below;

user_value="x-74523"

for FN in *astro__sys-*.txt;
do
sed -i 's/x-[a-zA-Z0-9]/"User": "`$user_value`"/g' $FN
done

output:

"User": ""User": "`$user_value`"3098"

Comment: @itgeek not clear to me what is your question or how I can help?

Comment: I'm exporting user value and referring that variable key name in the sed command.  export user_value="x-74523"

Comment: i ran this command to replace the value;                                                                                                                                                                         sed -i 's/x-[a-zA-Z0-9]/"User": "$user_value"/g' astro__sys-*.txt                                                                 Is this correct ?

Comment: Dear @itgeek you said you would like to replace `User": "x-73098` to `User": "sys_user` and `(x-73098)` is the same and `x` is different if so, the commands above should work for you

Comment: Thanks @Goro. One last question, how to exclude replacing values in a file astro_dev_sys-*.txt

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for FN in astro*.txt; do sed -r 's/(User: ")x-[[:digit:]]*"/\1sys_user"/' "$FN" > /tmp/TMP$$; mv /tmp/TMP$$ "$FN"; done
```